# Why can't my code detect cms when I add a letter to a string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a tool that looks up what CMS a website is using. And it works kind of.

When I use this:

```
const detectCMS = (): string => {
  if (document.documentElement.innerHTML.includes('<meta name="')) {
    return 'WordPress'
```

It works just fine. But the second I add

```
const detectCMS = (): string => {
  if (document.documentElement.innerHTML.includes('<meta name="generator" ')) {
    return 'WordPress'
```

It can't detect the CMS anymore, despite having those exact words. It's like whenever I add a letter after the: "". It is no longer able to identify it.

I have tried using `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML` to no avail, I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `if (document.querySelector('meta[name*="generator"]'))`

Comment: I tried doing as you stated, but nothing changed sadly. Also tried with the outerHTML but it seemed to break the function. I'm still learning, but thank you for your input!